# How to use Windows 7 driver in Windows 10

Tags: drivers

I have upgraded to Windows 10 and it was awesome! Until I can't play Minecraft. I tried upgrading my drivers but there is no plans to support the G43/G45 graphics driver. How can I get the Windows 7 driver for this?

I tryed asking here:https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239110/minecraft-crash-org-lwjgl-lwjglexception-pixel-format-not-accelerated

Comment: If there is no driver for windows 10 I don't think installing windows 7 driver would make any difference. Search for Windows 8 driver [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/) and see if it makes your gaming experience any better which i doubt as native driver Windows 10 has must be the best you can have in this situation

Comment: I can't find the windows 8 driver

Comment: If you can't find one then you are stuck with the native driver which your Windows 10 already has installed for you if it is up-to-date

Comment: oh then how can I play minecraft?(desktop verison)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no plans to develop Windows 10 drivers for the Intel(R)
>   G43/G45 Express Chipset.
>
> I am sorry for the inconvenience but we only have Windows XP, Vista,
>   win7 drivers for this product.  You can find drivers for your product
>   via Windows Update

[Intel Community Forms](https://communities.intel.com/thread/49444)

So you are stuck, you cannot play Minecraft in Windows 10.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled Windows 10 then had Windows 7 again. Then I installed Windows 10 on to a partition and I thought that drivers are stored in partitions but when I went to Windows 7 and tried Minecraft it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 supply you the better experience of installing system drivers as it automatically search the drivers you want and we only want to do is give the command to download those updates and install them. Dont download drivers from other web sites. Try windows update center to download your drivers. Thank you.

Comment: should I go to device manager and update driver software from windows update?

Answer (score -1):

Got a new pc, wayyyy more better than my other pc.

Well, the only way to fix this is by reverting back to Windows 7.

If you don't want to, your pretty much screwed until Intel created a new driver(which is going to be NEVER).

Comment: I see this already attracted a -1. You might want to consider why (e.g. how does this help other people with the same problem; why was this the only solution? etc etc).